# Realm do a IN query in android

Tags: android, realm

Is is possible to do a "IN" query with Realm in android? I mean, doing the equivalent of "SELECT X FROM X WHERE x IN (...)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you plan to have a lot of items inside the `IN ()`?

Comment: It may depend on the case. I have an array of profiles, and I want to find all contacts that are in this array. And the inverse case, all contacts that are not in this array. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Looks like a user named kneth might [have an answer](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/841#issuecomment-73662966) related to this type of question.

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't there be an .or() in that suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

The official `IN` operator (since 1.2.0) works like this:

```
public RealmQuery<E> in(String fieldName, String[] values) {
    if (values == null || values.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(EMPTY_VALUES);
    }
    beginGroup().equalTo(fieldName, values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        or().equalTo(fieldName, values[i]);
    }
    return endGroup();
}
```

Comment: Since 1.2.0, not 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

In java:

```
RealmResults dogs = realm
             .where(Dog.class)
             .in("name", new String[] {"Larry","Curly","Moe"})
             .findAll();
```

In kotlin (note that `in` is a keyword so, check the syntax changes):

```
val dogs = realm
     .where<Dog>()
     .`in`("name", arrayOf("Larry", "Curly", "Moe"))
```

Or

```
val dogs = realm
     .where<Dog>()
     .anyOf("age", arrayOf("Larry", "Curly", "Moe"))
```